# Use Genymotion/Andy without Host-Only Network Adapter?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, android, network-adapter

Genymotion and Andy require Virtualbox Host-Only Network Adapter, however [my computer is unable to install the driver correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/856082/virtualbox-network-adapter-fails-to-install?noredirect=1#comment1133417_856082). Note that Android x86 works well with default NAT network settings.

Genymotion and Andy fail to load when the Host-Only adapter is not found and changing the network device to NAT in both cases makes the VM terminal to output this indefinitely:

```
init: untracked pid 0001 exited
init: untracked pid 0002 exited
init: untracked pid 0003 exited
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

My first guess at this issue might be that the version of VirtualBox you are using could have a problem.  My understanding is that DHCP addresses for the Host-only adapter come from VirtualBox.  Maybe that functionality is not operating properly.

VirtualBox has known problems now with versions '6.1.32' and '6.1.34', especially noted with Bridged Adapter network settings and compatibility with Ubuntu version '20.04'.  My success with functionality and stability came with recovery or rolling back to version 6.1.30.  However, I read one post that stated that a move to NAT, or maybe NAT Network, reduced or eliminated issues with version '6.1.32' or '6.1.34' or both.  On version '6.1.34', I also received a repeating flashing annoying message of an event processing failure.  But this was not as bad as having my screen freeze as I experienced with these two newer versions when using a Bridged Network adapter with my VMs.  I would recommend sticking with VirtualBox version '6.1.30' for now, until a new version of VirtualBox appear greater than version '6.1.34'.